# Trying to save images in ipad app bundle from photo library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

```
-(IBAction)saveImage{



    NSMutableArray *dictWords= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TIGER",@"CAT", @"ROSE", @"ELEPHANT",@"MOUSE IS LOOKING FOR THE CHEESE",@"KITE",@"CAR",@"AEROPLANE",@"MANGO",@"FRUITS ARE FALLING FROM THE TREE",@"MOUNTAIN",@"BIRDS ARE FLYING",@"IGLOO",@"THIS HOUSE IS BUILT OF WOODS",@"BANANA",@"RAINBOW",@"TRAIN",@"DADDY DRINKS JUICE",@"UMBRELLA",@"GOAT",@"CAT JUMPS HIGH",@"DOG RUNS FAST",@"BUS",@"GIRL IS CRYING",@"STARS",@"DOLPHIN",@"BOYS ARE PLAYING FOOTBALL",@"GLASS IS FULL OF WATER",@"SHIP",@"SNOWFALL",@"GHOST",@"RABBIT",@"WATERMELON",@"SPIDERMAN",@"DINOSAUR",@"MICKEY MOUSE",@"MONKEY IS SITTING ON A TREE",@"PEACOCK",@"LIGHTNING",@"HEN LAYS EGGS",nil];
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[youSaid text] ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Image"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (int i=0 ; i<[assets count]; i++) {         
        if (i<[dictWords count]) {          
            [dict setObject:[[[assets objectAtIndex:i] defaultRepresentation] url] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictWords objectAtIndex:i]]];       
            NSLog(@"diccount:%d",[dict count]);   
        }
    }

     NSURL *imageurl = [dict objectForKey:[youSaid text]];    
    //NSLog(@"text:%@",[youSaid text]); 
    //Getting asset from url
    typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
    typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error); 

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
        //Setting asset image to image view according to the image url
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref]];
        youSaid.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageurl];



    }; 
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error, cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    }; 
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary assetForURL:imageurl resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock]; 

    UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];




NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", youSaid.text]]; //add our image to the path

[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the image

NSLog(@"image saved");
}

@end
```

This is the following code i wrote but i am not able to save images.i am only able to sane an image known as NULL.png .please suggest the changes to save all the pics in my library to bundle.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: Hi Christina, are you check that UIImage *image is nil or not? and imageData is nil or not?

Comment: i think thats nil ,that is the problem hell i am so confused in getting images from imageview to image,can u plz tell me that

Comment: sorry cant can u specify me the changes in my code please...

Comment: Are you fetching the image from image view? Bellow my ans is save image from Photolibrary.

Comment: i am also fetching my image from photo library and saving to app bundle but to no use just look at my code and tell the changes where i have to make

Comment: Can you tell what value comes for imageurl, path, youSaid.text?

Comment: you said text is what i speak ,but rest values i am not able to find ,i am a newbee in this

Comment: For get the value of variable, use NSLog(@"imageurl - %@", imageurl); NSLog(@"path - %@", path); NSLog(@"youSaid.text - %@", youSaid.text);

Comment: ya i got it thanx buddy ,i was doing a small mistake,thanks for ur help and hope to get your help in future too

Comment: Can you say me what the small mistake?

Comment: i was giving the url of the image to be saved but i changed that to a particular mane of an image and that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Code

```
    - (void) openPhotoLibrary {
        NSLog(@"openPhotolibrary");

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            if (self.picker != nil) {
                NSLog(@"releasing self.picker...");
                [self.picker release];
            }
            self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            //self.picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
            [self.picker presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];
            self.picker.delegate = self;

            [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:self.picker.view];
        }
    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)currentPicker {
        NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel");

        // hide the self.picker if user cancels picking an image.
        [currentPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        self.picker.view.hidden = YES;
        [self.picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)currentPicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
    {
        [self saveImage:image withImageName:@"myPhoto"];

    }

//saving an image

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image withImageName:(NSString*)imageName {

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]]; //add our image to the path

[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)

NSLog(@"image saved");

}
```

Comment: But it for the photo not for the video

Answer (score 0):

This code its working for me try it may be its helps you

```
-(IBAction)PhotoLibraryButtonClicked:(id)sender{
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]){


    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}
else{

    [self displaysorceError];

    }

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

//[self.popoverrcontroller dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
//[popoverrcontroller release];

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]){

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
//  UIImage *rote = [image rotateInDegrees:219.0f];

    img.image = image;
    if(newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil,nil, nil);
}else if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]){

    //not available vidio
}
}


-(IBAction)saveImageIn:(id)sender{

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img.image);

NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d.png",img.image]];

[fileMan createFileAtPath:fullPathToFile contents:imageData attributes:nil];



UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                    initWithTitle:@"Thank You" 
                    message:@"Image Save In Directory" 
                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alt show];
[alt release];
}
```

thank you..:)Neet